# browser.cookies.getAll storeId is always firefox-default

Tags: android, firefox-addon-webextensions, gecko, geckoview

This is concerning reading cookies with GeckoView on Android.

Based on https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1035417, we can only do so via web extensions.

---

In GeckoView, we can supply `contextId` when creating tabs. Doing so provides the id for the session's cookie store, and I can verify the behaviour by:

1. Changing the id and seeing that GeckoView uses a different cookie store
2. Calling `browser.cookies.getAllCookieStore` in a background script and seeing the list of containers.

However, when calling `browser.cookies.getAll({})`, I see that all the cookies are there, and that they all have `storeId` set to `firefox-default`. If I create two tabs with different `contextId`s and log into the same site, I see cookies from both logins under `firefox-default`. Is this a limitation of the current GeckoView implementation, or is there anything in particular I need to do to distinguish between the cookie stores?

---

- I'm using manifest 2; I've noticed that with manifest 3, I couldn't read cookies at all.
- I'm calling `browser.cookies` in a background script in a built in extension, within a callback (currently `browser.tabs.onActivated`)
- My manifest permissions:

```
"<all_urls>",
"activeTab",
"contextMenus",
"contextualIdentities",
"cookies",
"history",
"management",
"tabs",
"nativeMessaging",
"nativeMessagingFromContent",
"geckoViewAddons",
"webRequest"
```

They aren't all needed by I'm modelling it off of Firefox's [multi container extension](https://github.com/mozilla/multi-account-containers/blob/main/src/manifest.json)

I do also notice that that extension isn't available in Android.